Proving the local submersion theorem using the inverse function theorem
In my real analysis class, we received the following problem:

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, and $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^m$ a submersion. Show that for all $y = f(x)$ there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $y$, such that $N \subset f(\Omega)$.

Since we barely covered any differential geometry or topology, I am having issues understanding some of the proofs for the local submersion theorem, which seems to be equivalent to the statement above. I have attempted solving it by using the inverse function theorem, but I am unsure how to conclude my proof:
Let $x_0 \in \Omega$. We have $\text{rank} \: Df(x_0) = m$, so there exist $m$ linearly independent columns $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{k_1}}, ..., \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{k_m}}$ in the Jacobian of $f$. WLOG, let these be the first $m$ columns (so $x_{k_i} = x_i$ for all $i$). Now let $F: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n, x \mapsto (f(x), x_{m+1},...,x_n)$. We have that $DF(x_0)$ is an $n \times n$-matrix, which can be split into $3$ blocks as follows: the first $m$ columns are exactly the $m$ columns of $Df(x_0)$ (i.e. the top of the matrix is $Df(x_0)$), and below there is a zero matrix of dimension $(n-m) \times m$ on the left, and the identity matrix of dimension $n-m$ on the right. Therefore, we have $\text{rank} \: DF(x_0) = n$. As such, $DF(x_0)$ is invertible (and so the determinant is not $0$), and by the inverse function theorem there exists a neighborhood $U \subset \Omega$ of $x_0$, such that $F\mid_U$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism with inverse $G$. Since for all $x \in U$ we have that
$$x = (F|_U \circ G) (x) = (f|_U(G(x)), x_{m+1}, ..., x_n),$$
it follows that $f|_U(G(x)) = (x_1, ..., x_m)$.
I thought this would help me, as it follows that $f|_U$ is surjective since $f|_U \circ G$ is surjective, but this was already obvious since $f|_U$ is surjective essentially by definition! Is my entire approach wrong or am I simply missing a few steps at the end?

You’ve just reproved the local submersion theorem. So locally there are coordinates so that $f$ becomes a projection: $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(x_1,\dots x_m)$. But projections have the desired property. You need to now finish by translating back to define $N$.

Sorry, I don't understand how it follows that locally $f$ is a projection - haven't I instead shown that $f \circ G$ is one?

Yes, the diffeomorphism $G^{-1}$ gives you the right coordinates to use on $\Bbb R^n$.
